# Merge two or more columns dynamically based on table columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table which is called `SectionNames` as follows

```
SectionID   SectionCode     Subsection
   1            xYz         Individual
   2            xYz         Family
   3            CYD         Friends
   4            PCPO        level1
   5            PCPO        level2
   6            PCPO        level3
```

So on. So in future we can add one or more subsections for each section code.

And have one more table which is a reference table for above `SectionNames` table and `Employee` table with employee data.

```
ID    EmployeeID    SectionID   Cost    
1           1              1    $200
2           1              2    $300    
3           1              3    $40 
4           1              4    $10 
5           1              5    No Level
6           1              6    No Level
7           1              7    $20 
8           1              8    No Level
9           1              9    No Level
```

So Iwant the out put from these tables should look like:

```
EmployeeID     Individual_xyz_Cost    Family_xyz_Cost    Friends_xyz_cost  level1_PCPO_cost  level2_PCPO_Cost
   1                 $200                 $300               $400              $10             NoLevel
```

There are few employee records exists in my employee table. And I want this to be dynamic. Like If in future if one more subsection called `Relatives` added for `XYZ` section then my query should return `Relatives_XYZ_Cost`.

How can I write this query dynamically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will want to use the `PIVOT` function to transform the data from columns into rows.  If you are going to have an unknown number of values that need to be columns, then you will need to use dynamic SQL.

It is easier to see a static or hard-coded version first and then convert it into a dynamic SQL version.  A static version is used when you have a known number of values:

```
select *
from
(
  select e.employeeid,
    s.subsection +'_'+s.sectioncode+'_Cost' Section,
    e.cost
  from employee e
  inner join sectionnames s
    on e.sectionid = s.sectionid
) src
pivot
(
  max(cost)
  for section in (Individual_xYz_Cost, Family_xYz_Cost,
                  Friends_CYD_Cost, level1_PCPO_Cost,
                  level2_PCPO_Cost, level3_PCPO_Cost)
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1451/4).

If you need the query to be flexible, then you will convert this to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(subsection +'_'+sectioncode+'_Cost') 
                    from SectionNames
                    group by subsection, sectioncode, sectionid
                    order by sectionid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT employeeid,' + @cols + ' 
              from 
             (
                select e.employeeid,
                  s.subsection +''_''+s.sectioncode+''_Cost'' Section,
                  e.cost
                from employee e
                inner join sectionnames s
                  on e.sectionid = s.sectionid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(cost)
                for section in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b1451/8)

The result of both is:

```
| EMPLOYEEID | INDIVIDUAL_XYZ_COST | FAMILY_XYZ_COST | FRIENDS_CYD_COST | LEVEL1_PCPO_COST | LEVEL2_PCPO_COST | LEVEL3_PCPO_COST |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          1 |                $200 |            $300 |              $40 |              $10 |         No Level |         No Level |
```

Comment: Can I use this dynamic result set as follows to join with some other table:Inner Join(Result set) AS z ON z.ID = b.ID

Comment: @user1882705 Yes, you can just extend the sql string to place this select in a subquery

Comment: This is what I am trying :inner Join
 ( 
  execute (@query)
 )  
 AS z ON z.ID = b.ID      But getting error when executing the @query

Comment: @user1882705 You cannot do it that way, you have to place your other code inside of the dynamic sql string.